# Resource not found ERR:404 in express

Tags: node.js, express, web, backend

I am making a simple express app,using react (with cdn).But my browser `cannot get (resource not found ERR:404`) the app.js file in which I have written my react code although I am rendering this file in an another file **product.ejs** using **getelementbyid**,and this(product ) file is rendering fine in browser.

I have not written route for app.js file as i am rendering it in product.ejs file

**What can be the reason for this problem ?**

This is first time I am asking question on stackoverflow .So, please respond if I can ask it in a good other way ✌️

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please first read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then please share the relevant snippets of the source code.

Comment: Okay , I will definitely try to rewrite the question with details sufficient to understand the problem .